# How to tell whether it is a "development server"?

Tags: google-app-engine

Some of the Google App Engine documentation make reference to the term "development server".  What is a development server?  Besides development server, what are the other types of servers?

Is abc-def-123.appspot.com on a development server?  If it is, how do I deploy to a non-developmental server?  Is it just by `Enable Billing` in the Developers Console ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development server runs locally and allows you to run your AppEngine application entirely on your local machine during development. Other "servers" are the AppEngine production servers where you deploy your application when it's ready.

You use the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/) tool for such tasks.

When the app runs on a development the application id gets a `dev~` prefix.

Comment: Yes, I have deployed my application using `appcfg.py`.  It is running fine on xxx-abc-123.appspot.com.  Is this web site on a production server?  I am asking because a feature which the doc says will not run on a "development server" is not running on xxx-abc-123.appspot.com, and I am trying to narrow down the cause.

Comment: Yes, it's a production server. Development server is when you run it on your local system.